# Linking Rob Hess's SIFT library (in C, using OpenCV) with C++

Tags: c++, c, opencv, linkage, sift

I'm trying to use [Rob Hess's SIFT library](http://blogs.oregonstate.edu/hess/code/sift/) in my C++ project. I've looked through (the code of) other SIFT implementations, but this one seemed most phase-divided like the original Lowe's paper and also uses OpenCV which I am familiar with, so I chose this one.

Unfortunately, I've had only trouble since I've tried using it in C++. The library is originally written in C with OpenCV.

I have tried compiling my code both with and without surrounding the C library include-s with `extern`, but neither works. I think I have diagnosed what the problems are in both cases, but I don't know how to solve them and I would very much appreciate any help.

Problems (or at least, what I think the problems are):

- withouth `extern`: doesn't work because of C++ name-mangling (I've checked, and of course all the function names are decorated)
- with `extern` : doesn't work because OpenCV can detect weather it's compiled for C or C++. There are no linkage problems with any of the SIFT library functions, but now OpenCV includes C++ headers, and since in the main program it's ultimately included in the `extern` block, I get (literally hundereds) of errors like these:

  `/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/mat.hpp:2361: error: template with C linkage`

I have been trying to make this work for the last couple of days, so if anyone has tried to work with the same SIFT library in C++ or has experienced similar problems with a different library, help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like I've managed to find quite a nice solutions. Two ways, easy and elegant:

**Easy:**

Just include all the OpenCV headers used in the library (and any other OpenCV headers needed) *before* the `extern "C"` section including all the SIFT library headers.

**Elegant**

In all the library headers, add the sections `extern "C"` around all the code *except* the OpenCV includes, like so:

```
// OpenCV includes:
#include "cxcore.h"
#include ....

#if __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

...
function definitions in the header file
...

#if __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Now all the library includes can be `#include`d directly in the C++ code without the `extern "C"`. The OpenCV libraries compile correctly for C/C++ (depending on the compiler), and the relative order of the additional OpenCV includes and the SIFT library includes doesn't matter.

Comment: looks like I can't accept my own answer for 2 more days, but this solved the problem and I'll accept my answer as soon as I can. Hope this helps someone else :)